# Software to Generate Image EXIF Metadata Table / Embed EXIF Data to Images in Bulk

Tags: images, metadata, exif

I'm struggling to find a software which:

1. Takes N images
2. For each image, create a row in a table which contains the image, GPS coordinates, and timestamp
3. Export the table in PDF

Alternatively, a software which does this would also work:

1. Takes N images
2. For each image, append a white rectangle underneath it with some EXIF metadata (i.e. GPS coordinates and timestamp)
3. Exports each image to a separate folder

So far I have only been able to find viewer programs such as MesaExif and ExifEditor for the Mac, but nothing which outputs EXIF medatada in bulk alongside the images themselves. ex

Comment: Are you familiar with the ImageMagick.org suite of tools?

Comment: You can create a script by using exiftool that does that, not sure it can create pdf files though...

Comment: What kind of table to create? And what did you try so far?

Comment: Hey, @barrycarter yes I've used ImageMagick.org before, but I believe it's primarily directed at image manipulation, not metadata reporting. A quick search didn't turn up many promising avenues: https://imagemagick.org/script/search.php?q=exif&sa= But please let me know if I'm wrong and I'm missing something!

Comment: @RicardoBohner This is great! I found this article which seems very promising: https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=2681.0 Do you have a command/approach in mind you could share?

Comment: @RomeoNinov I am looking to create a table with the following columns: 

Image (showing a thumbnail of the image)
GPS Coordinates
Timestamp (of when the photo was taken)

My goal is to be able to provide an easy way to see both the images and their exif data for multiple images. Hence my idea was to do so in a table. 

Besides the MesaExif and ExifEditor software which weren't very helpful, I'm now looking into using exiftool. Do you have any pointers or suggestions you could share? :)

Comment: The `identify` tool is all about the metadata :) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654709/extract-exif-data-as-text-using-imagemagick

Comment: @wixoft142, you do not get it. Table is visual representation of data, do you want to be html, excel, etc table? See my answer

Comment: Thank you @barrycarter I will look into this! :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov Absolutely agreed - I would be happy with an excel/html table without any preference for the end format. Thank you for your answer detailing the exiftool command - this is very useful!

Comment: please check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to create `CSV` file:

```
exiftool  -gpslatitude -gpslongitude -DateTimeOriginal -csv -T <path/to/images>
```

Then you can redirect the result to file and import it in your instrument for further manipulation.

Here is what I get as result on Windows 10, exiftool v12.28:

```
d:\photo\new\Aheloy\20220699>c:\tools\exiftool  -gpslatitude -gpslongitude -DateTimeOriginal -csv -T export
SourceFile,GPSLatitude,GPSLongitude,DateTimeOriginal
export/_M2A4848.jpg,"42 deg 38' 18.85"" N","27 deg 38' 50.18"" E",2022:06:17 10:12:41
export/_M2A4853.jpg,"42 deg 38' 18.85"" N","27 deg 38' 50.18"" E",2022:06:17 10:12:42
export/_M2A4855.jpg,"42 deg 38' 18.85"" N","27 deg 38' 50.18"" E",2022:06:17 10:13:06
```

You can try with specific parameter (thank you @Izzy) to create `html` table

```
exiftool  -filename -gpslatitude -gpslongitude -DateTimeOriginal -h -T .
<!-- ./_M2A4848.jpg -->
<table>
<tr><td>_M2A4848.jpg</td></tr>
<tr><td>42 deg 38&#39; 18.85&quot; N</td></tr>
<tr><td>27 deg 38&#39; 50.18&quot; E</td></tr>
<tr><td>2022:06:17 10:12:41</td></tr>
</table>
<!-- ./_M2A4853.jpg -->
<table>
<tr><td>_M2A4853.jpg</td></tr>
<tr><td>42 deg 38&#39; 18.85&quot; N</td></tr>
<tr><td>27 deg 38&#39; 50.18&quot; E</td></tr>
<tr><td>2022:06:17 10:12:42</td></tr>
</table>
```

to convert it to PDF you can use something like:

```
exiftool  -filename -gpslatitude -gpslongitude -DateTimeOriginal -h -T . | pandoc -o exif.pdf
```

Comment: `exiftool -gpslatitude -gpslongitude -DateTimeOriginal -h -T <path/to/images>` – no idea why it puts the file name as a comment instead of a column, or one could directly pipe that to e.g. pandoc to create a PDF…

Comment: @Izzy, maybe the output depend of the OS we run the tool.

Comment: I won't doubt that (which is why I made it a comment and not an edit) – it might as well depend on the version of exiftool used. I'm using the one shipping with my distributions repo, being on Linux Mint 20.3. I was hoping the output could directly be used, but for me the file name is just put into a `<!-- comment -->` unfortunately. Is that not the case for you? Then the output of my example command could simply be piped to `| pandoc -o exif.pdf`.

Comment: @Izzy, add result for Windows 10, exiftool v 12.28

Comment: Thanks! What does it look like when replacing `-csv` by `-h`? Is the filename again just a comment, or included as normal cell? Btw: 11.88 here on Linux (no idea why it wasn't updated – most likely because of "LTS").

Comment: @Izzy, very good, thank you, just need to add explicitly `-filename` and you will have formatted as tables. :)

Comment: That did the trick for me, too, thanks! Remark: the order of parameters also defines the order of columns (i.e. putting `-filename` first will make it the first column – putting it last makes it the last column). Just a pity that each cell is put in its own row. That can be fixed by piping the `exiftool` output through `sed` first: `sed 's!<table>!<table><tr>!g;s!</table>!</tr></table>!g;s!<tr><td>!<td>!g;s!</td></tr>!</td>!g'` (and feel free to inject some CSS along the way). That still has each file in its own table, though.

Comment: Also take a look at the [`-p` (`-printFormat`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#p-FMTFILE-or-STR--printFormat).  With that, you can create a FMT file and define a header and trailer and exactly how you want each line of data to be formatted.  As an example, the `-p` option can be used to output GPS data from files into a GPX file.  See the [`GPS.fmt`](https://github.com/exiftool/exiftool/blob/master/fmt_files/gpx.fmt) file on Github.

Comment: @StarGeek, thank you for the hint. IMHO OP want to have it in kind of table for (probably) offline save.